# Forgot Rstudio password on cloud server

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried to log into my Rstudio on the cloud server through :8787, only to find that I forget the password. I could log in the Rstudio on my other computer, because somehow the computer remembers the password. What can I do to change the password from inside the Rstudio from my other computer, or from the Ubuntu system on which the Rstudio was built?

Comment: This would be quickly answered if you post on RStudio's community website: [R Studio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/)